# How to build a static scrollbar in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

basically I have to achieve the `stacic scrolling content` section part. The top static border, and the bottom static border have to stay always visible regardless of the size of the browser, and the `static scrolling content` should adapt to this resizing happening.

[image]

I've been playing quite a lot with the `overflow-y:hidden` container with a `overflow-y:scroll` in a child container with no success.

This is what I've been trying:

```
    .vertical-scroll-viewer {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;*/
}

    .vertical-scroll-viewer-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    /*
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;*/
}
```

And the HTML:

```
  <html>
<head>   
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Header1</h1>
    <div class="vertical-scroll-viewer">

        <div class="vertical-scroll-viewer-content ">
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
            <div>  hi  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1> Header2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Header 2 dissapears below the scrollbar.

Does anyone know how to make this? Thanks!

Comment: Please, show what you tried. Both markup and css.

Comment: please add your code that you have tried.

Comment: I edited the question with the HTML and the CSS

Comment: While CSS scrollbar style support is a bit scattered it's getting better. Your closest to universal support would be something such as `scrollbar-color: #000 #fff;` though if you want to create your own don't forget about accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works well.

Notice the reset of the html/body and the use of vh,vw instead of 100%

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; margin: 0; }

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 15vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.static {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#left {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

#middle {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-y: scroll; /* it will work */
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="top" class="static">Top</div>
    <div id="middle">
      <h2>Middle</h2>
      <p style="height: 9001px;">Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="static">Bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="scroll">
    <h2>Right</h2>
    <p style="height: 9001px;">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes is more or less what I need, but the Middle section should stay always visible, and the bottom part too. The Middle section + top + bottom should be always visible, regardless the Right section.

Comment: Hi, it worked when I copied it in a local html file. the top, bottom part are always shown, but If I scroll in the main part it will scroll everything also. Is there any way to make it static as the menu in StackOverflow? I'll mark it as answered and ask for who to do the static StackOverflow menuin another question. Thanks again.

Comment: I think if you add `height: 70vh;` instead of   `height: calc(100vh - 100px);` and adding `height: 15vh;` to the two elements Top and Bottom might work

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" style="width:200px; height: 500px;position:relative;">
    <div id="div2" style="max-height:100%;overflow:auto;border:1px solid red;">
        <div id="div3" style="height:1500px;border:5px solid yellow;">hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: Thanks but that solution doesn't adapt to the size of the height of the browser: https://imgur.com/a/bBCbu8I as you can see the Hello scrollbar dissapears overflowing the bottom.